# How to Embed Tweet Stream with Electron?

Tags: electron

I am building an electron app and trying to use the twitter embed link from https://publish.twitter.com/

However, only the text shows up as a link, and not the actual stylized tweet timeline stream.

Any help would be appreciated! Here is what the code looks like so far.

```html
      </header>

        <script>
            componentDidMount: function () {
                twttr.widgets.load()
            }
        </script>

        <a class="twitter-timeline"
            href="https://twitter.com/cs484project?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"
            data-width="300"
            data-height="300">
            Tweets by cs484project
        </a>
        <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>
  <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
</html>
```

Note: The `componentDidMount()` and `twtter.widgets.load()` came from another exchange forum, which I tried but still has not worked for me.